# Android Studio - install apk failure

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I've tried to build .apk, so I have chosen Gradle tab from the right side, select my app, then ":app" and then "assemble"->Run. Now i have app-release-unsigned.apk file, but when I try to install it I get message "App is not installed". What can I do, to make it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your android device can't run unsigned apk, you need to [sign it](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: Ok, it works now, thank you! I'm pretty sure, but can you confirm that when I install new release version of the app, the old databse connected with the the app remains and I will have access to it?

Comment: @meDarq: TBH i dont know.